# How can I make an odd-numbered list of questions/solutions?

Tags: lists, enumerate

I'm trying to make two odd-numbered lists, one with excercises and the other one with solutions, but the latter should have only 4k+1 odd-numbered items.
Example: 
List of questions:
1)
3)
5)
7)
etc
List of solutions
1)
5)
9)
13)
Which commands should I use??

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Take a look at the [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) for a package which gives you control over the appearance of lists such as enumerate.

Comment: What is *k* here? And how does (say) having *q* questions translate into *4k + 1* items?

Comment: @Werner I guess he means `$k \in \mathbb{N}^+$` (or he wants 4001 odd-numbered items, who knows)

Comment: Sorry,  I'm going to edit my quesiton.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope I got your question right. Here is a rather primitive way of accomplishing what I hope you want:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\let\itembak\item
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\odditems}[1][2]{%
    \setcounter{\@listctr}{\numexpr1-#1}%
    \renewcommand{\item}[1][]{%
        \addtocounter{\@listctr}{\numexpr#1-1}%
        \ifx\relax##1\relax%
            \itembak%
        \else%
            \itembak[##1]%
        \fi%
    }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent
first:
\begin{enumerate}
    \odditems
    \item first
    \item second
    \item third
\end{enumerate}
second:
\begin{enumerate}
    \odditems[4]
    \item first
    \item second
    \item third
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: The enumerate is nestable (but in a counter intuitive way):

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \odditems
    \item first
    \item second
    \item third
        \begin{enumerate}
            \odditems[1]% this second call of \odditems allows the nested use
            \item third.first
            \item third.second
            \item third.third
        \end{enumerate}
    \item fourth
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: @Juani though I am glad that it works and is what you wanted, you should not accept this answer just now. It is (almost) always better to wait a few hours so you might get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

The following example provides an automated way of setting `questions` and `answers`. (Expandable) calculations are provided by [`xfp`](//ctan.org/pkg/xfp) and can be generalised as needed:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xfp}

\newcounter{question}\newcounter{question@}
\newenvironment{questions}
  {\setcounter{question@}{0}%
   \begin{enumerate}
     \let\olditem\item
     \renewcommand{\item}{%
       \setcounter{question}{\fpeval{2*\value{question@}}}\refstepcounter{question}%
       \olditem[\thequestion)]\leavevmode\stepcounter{question@}%
     }}
  {\end{enumerate}}

\newcounter{answer}\newcounter{answer@}
\newenvironment{answers}
  {\setcounter{answer@}{0}%
   \begin{enumerate}
     \let\olditem\item
     \renewcommand{\item}{%
       \setcounter{answer}{\fpeval{4*\value{answer@}}}\refstepcounter{answer}%
       \olditem[\theanswer)]\leavevmode\stepcounter{answer@}%
     }}
  {\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}

Questions:
\begin{questions}
  \item first
  \item second
  \item third
  \item fourth
\end{questions}

Answers:
\begin{answers}
  \item first
  \item second
  \item third
  \item fourth
\end{answers}

\end{document}
```

The modification of `\item` doesn't allow for nesting of other lists within `questions` or `answers`.

Comment: I don't get why you need `xfp` for that. You could use `\addtocounter{answer@}{4}` instead of the `\fpeval{4*\value{anwer@}` (same is true for `question`). What is the advantage of using the package?

Comment: @skillmon True; I reference the fact that with [`xfp`](//ctan.org/pkg/xfp) one can generalize the calculation to anything arbitrary.