# How to select and print selected items from a list

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem, ifthenelse

I have written a solutions manual for a textbook and need to print only the odd numbered solutions.  I formatted the text very simply with \enumerate within each section.

Sample code:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\item
\item
\end{enumerate}
```

It seems every bit of info I find does not quite fit what I want to do, since I am trying to work on lists generated using `\item`.

How can I do this?  Thanks.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/372087/197451

Answer (score 2):

Welcome! This is a simple way, i.e. something that does not need packages, that works for lists that have an odd number of entries. This update uses [information from this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27578) to make it work at all levels.

```
\documentclass{article} %
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\OnlyOddItems}{\let\olditem\item
\def\item##1\item{%
\expandafter\stepcounter{enum\romannumeral\@enumdepth}\olditem}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Original:
\begin{enumerate} 
\item A
\item B
\item C
\item D
\item E
\end{enumerate}

Modified:
\begin{enumerate}
\item A \OnlyOddItems 
\item B
\item C
\item D
\item E
\end{enumerate}

Modified at a deeper level:
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{enumerate}
\item A \OnlyOddItems 
\item B
\item C
\item D
\item E
\end{enumerate}
\item purr
\item pft
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, if you want 1., 2., 3. instead.

```
\documentclass{article} %
\newcommand{\OnlyOddItems}{\let\olditem\item
\def\item##1\item{\olditem}}
\begin{document}
Original:
\begin{enumerate} 
\item A
\item B
\item C
\item D
\item E
\end{enumerate}

Modified:
\begin{enumerate}
\item A \OnlyOddItems 
\item B
\item C
\item D
\item E
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  Actually, I want to preserve the answers that go with the odd numbers and print only the odd numbered items:

Comment: Ex: Old list: 1.A, 2.B, 3.C.  New list 1.A, 3.C etc.  It is just deleting the even numbered items for printing, but preserving all the solutions from the original manual. One document, but 2 different printed versions - one for instructors, one of students. I hope this clarifies it.

Comment: Actually, you seemed to have answered my question for an odd number of items...I need a general solution.

Comment: Actually, I can create a mirror student manual with all the last even numbers in the list tagged as comments - so all my lists have an odd number of items.  I will play with this.  Many thanks.

Comment: I am not too well versed with coding -- how about applying this process to the deeper levels enumii, etc.

Comment: @JuanMolina For deeper levels one can replace `enumi` by `enumii` and so on, e.g. `\newcommand{\OnlyOddItems}{\let\olditem\item
\def\item##1\item{\stepcounter{enumii}\olditem}}`. I'll see if one can autodetect the level (I think this is possible).

Comment: @JuanMolina I changed the version you seem be looking at to work at all levels.

Comment: Man, you know your stuff!  Last wrench to throw at you.  How about for this? Old list 1A, 2B, 3C 4a)D, b)E, 5a)F, b)G, c)H  into new list 1A, 3C, 5a)F, b)G, c)H preserving all the options from the next level, enumii. Thaks

Comment: @JuanMolina I am sorry, this is becoming too complicated for basic codes, you may need heavier machinery like in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/524727.

Comment: Thanks anyways- you have given me a way to start fixing it.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to nest lists in the solutions, I chose to introduce solutions with `\sol` instead of `\item`.

This makes it possible to store the solutions in a sequence and to only output those we want.

I define three possible choices: `even`, `odd` or `list`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,enumitem}

\newlist{innersolutions}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[innersolutions]{label=\arabic*.}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{solutions}{O{} +b}
 {
  \begin{innersolutions}
  \molina_solutions:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  \end{innersolutions}
 }
 {}

\seq_new:N \l__molina_solutions_items_seq
\clist_new:N \l__molina_solutions_list_clist

\keys_define:nn { molina/solutions }
 {
  odd  .code:n = \cs_set_eq:NN \__molina_solutions_if_good:nTF \int_if_odd:nTF,
  even .code:n = \cs_set_eq:NN \__molina_solutions_if_good:nTF \int_if_even:nTF,
  list .code:n = \clist_set:Nn \l__molina_solutions_list_clist { #1 }
                 \cs_set:Npn \__molina_solutions_if_good:nTF ##1 ##2 ##3
                  {
                   \clist_if_in:NnTF \l__molina_solutions_list_clist { ##1 } { ##2 } { ##3 }
                  },
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \molina_solutions:nn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__molina_solutions_items_seq { \sol } { #2 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l__molina_solutions_items_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \keys_set:nn { molina/solutions } { #1 }
  \seq_indexed_map_function:NN \l__molina_solutions_items_seq \__molina_solutions_item:nn
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__molina_solutions_item:nn
 {
  \__molina_solutions_if_good:nTF { #1 }
   {
    \item #2
   }
   {
    \stepcounter{innersolutionsi}
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Odd numbered
\begin{solutions}[odd]
\sol yes
\sol no
\sol yes
\sol no
\end{solutions}

Even numbered
\begin{solutions}[even]
\sol no
\sol yes
\sol no
\sol yes
\sol no
\end{solutions}

Chosen 
\begin{solutions}[list={1,3,4,6}]
\sol yes
\sol no
\sol yes
\sol yes
\sol no
\sol yes
\end{solutions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Since I am a newbee, I was thinking along the lines of tagging each of the solutions (or text) - (I coded them as \item) that I want to print and then ask latex to only print the tagged items. Is this possible in a simple way?

I need to generate a print ready version of both the student's solution manual (odd problems) and the instrutor's soln manual (all problems), keeping chapter, section, subsection headings.  I have two levels of solutions (enumi, enumii) since there are some exercises with parts a,b,c, etc.

Your wisdom is appreciated.

Comment: Also, can I use \item?  I already wrote 4 chapters and changing to \sol would be quite a feat.  Thx

Comment: @JuanMolina Provided you don't plan to use nested lists, yes.

Comment: Egreg, many thanks.  I will try it.  I have some solutions where there are parts a,b,c, etc.  Would your procedure work, if adapted?

Comment: I coded as follows

Comment: \begin{enumerate} \item \item \begin{enumerate} \item \end{enumerate} \item \end{enumerate} - This is the format of almost 600 solutions I have written.